# The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net

I have this error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception.
  at System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String value)
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HtmlEncode(String value)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.set_InnerText(String value)
  at HomePage_index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\macher.co.il\httpdocs\HomePage\index.aspx.cs:line 16
  at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)System.Web Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
```

My website in vps server. I have no idea why does it happen.
p.s. just sometimes the error raised

**Edit:**
I delete the row 16 from my page, and so I the same error but without the line that mention the specific page. although I pen attention that the error occurred before enter to the `Web_Application` func in the Global.asax

Comment: Some strings stored somewhere has some invalid character that are throwing this exception. This HtmlEncode method is used in almost every server control. You should post more information

Comment: @Fals, it occured to **all** the pages that in files and not on the root. so i think the problem is global, which information to give?

Comment: Given that It's Global, you should start to look at the Master Page. Probly some control is receiving something with invalid characteres.

Comment: @Fals, which type of characteres can be invalid? and if so, why does it happen sometimes and not always

Comment: Take a deeply look at c:\inetpub\vhosts\macher.co.il\httpdocs\HomePage\index.aspx.cs:line 16 at. You will see what is wrong! Debug it, see values and everything you can dig.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced it myself.  My stack trace is below.

Everybody should note that this is the type initializer/static constructor throwing the error.  There's not much that user code could be doing to cause this.

We did install .net 4.5 on our server about 3 months ago, but have not had issues since up until now.

Of particular interest is the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion attrib on the pages element.  I may try removing that and see if it helps.

Other information is here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1863996.aspx?The+type+initializer+for+System+Net+WebUtility+threw+an+exception

I may see if I have a credit for an support incident or log a connect article if I can't find anything further.

I realize this is not an answer but until a solution is found I wanted to post beyond the limits of the comment box.

Stack Trace:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception. ---> System.Web.HttpException
    at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
    at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
    at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
    at System.Net.WebUtility..cctor()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String value, TextWriter output)
    at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RenderHiddenFields(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.BeginFormRender(HtmlTextWriter writer, String formUniqueID)
    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)